# Jenkins test results behaviour

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, junit, continuous-integration

I am new to Jenkins and of late I observed that in one of the job  when i build application test results are changing even though new changes are not committed.

Out of curiousity I run that job multiple times.
So the test results are like this

1st build: test cases run:100 failed:0 errors:22

2nd build: test cases run:100 failed:0 errors:70

3rd build: test cases run:100 failed:0 errors:60

Build became unstable

Those test cases are negative test cases.
But why this is happening? Is this normal??

Note: we are using junit

Comment: Jenkins is just executing your test, the issue must be with your tests.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually they are not failed but gave errors. Though build got successful because they ignored those errors and when I try to publish them in post build actions the build became unstable.